# Column Filter or Column Searcher in DisplayTag is possible?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, full-text-search, search-engine, displaytag

Is it possible to create a Column Filter Function (searcher in a table) in a list returned by a Spring MVC controller which then completes a DisplayTag in a JSP?

I can not find a solution without having to submit a new query with the selected filters.

Thanks for all...
Cheers.

CaktusJP

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter a table that has been already rendered you can use [quicksearch jquery plugin](http://lomalogue.com/jquery/quicksearch/)